# Remove duplicated rows when column above a threshold in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello everyone I ould need help in order to remove duplicate rows from a df only when a column is higher than a threshold.

Here is a dataframe :

```
  Group       Species Values
1    G1 Cattus_cattus     10
2    G1 Cattus_cattus     10
3    G1 Cattus_cattus     10
4    G2   Canis_lupus      2
5    G2   Canis_lupus      2
6    G3  Griseus_lupa     90
7    G4  Griseus_lupa     89
```

I would liek to remove duplicated `c(Group,Species)` when `Values>5`
Here I should then get :

```
  Group       Species Values
1    G1 Cattus_cattus     10
4    G2   Canis_lupus      2
5    G2   Canis_lupus      2
6    G3  Griseus_lupa     90
7    G4  Griseus_lupa     89
```

**the data**

```
structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Canis_lupus", "Cattus_cattus", 
"Griseus_lupa"), class = "factor"), Values = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 
2L, 2L, 90L, 89L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
    filter(!duplicated(x)| Values <=5)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `duplicated` and combine it with an *or* `|` testing for `x$Values < 5`.

```
x[!duplicated(x) | x$Values <= 5,]
#x[!(duplicated(x) & x$Values > 5),] #Alternative
#  Group       Species Values
#1    G1 Cattus_cattus     10
#4    G2   Canis_lupus      2
#5    G2   Canis_lupus      2
#6    G3  Griseus_lupa     90
#7    G4  Griseus_lupa     89
```

Or only for *Group* and *Species*:

```
x[!(duplicated(x[c("Group","Species")]) & x$Values > 5),]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>%
   group_by(Group, Species) %>% 
   slice(if(any(Values > 5)) 1 else 1:n())

# output:
# Groups:   Group, Species [4]
  Group Species       Values
  <fct> <fct>          <int>
1 G1    Cattus_cattus     10
2 G2    Canis_lupus        2
3 G2    Canis_lupus        2
4 G3    Griseus_lupa      90
5 G4    Griseus_lupa      89
```